# Laurent series of cotangent

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, laurent-series

Compute the principal part of the Laurent series of $\cot(\pi z)$ on $1<|z|<2$.

EDIT: After using either of the approaches below, we get that the principal part is equal to

$$ \frac 1 \pi \left( \frac 3 z  + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac 2 {z^{2n+1}}\right)$$

Comment: Do you think that logarithm is well-defined around the whole circle?

Comment: oh, good point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Recalling that:
$$ \frac{\sin(\pi z)}{\pi z}=\prod_{n\geq 1}\left(1-\frac{z^2}{n^2}\right)\tag{1}$$
and considering $\frac{d}{dz}\log(\cdot)$ of both sides we have:
$$ -\frac{1}{z}+\pi\cot(\pi z) = \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{2z}{z^2-n^2}\tag{2} $$
or:
$$ \cot(\pi z)=\frac{1}{\pi z}+\frac{2}{\pi}\sum_{n\geq 1}\left(\frac{1}{z-n}+\frac{1}{z+n}\right).\tag{3}$$
Can you finish from there?

Comment: yes. thanks much!

Answer (score 2):

Another approach: In $\{|z|<2\},$ $\cot \pi z$ has only three singularities, namely simple poles at $0,1,-1.$ If we let $a,b,c$ be the residues of $\cot \pi z$ at these points (and these are fairly easy to obtain), then

$$\cot \pi z -\left (\frac{a}{z}+\frac{b}{z-1}+\frac{c}{z+1}\right )$$

is analytic on $\{|z|<2\}.$ Thus the expression in parentheses will be the desired principal part. So all we need to do is find the Laurent expansions of $1/z,1/(z-1),1/(z+1)$ in the annulus $\{1<|z|<2\}.$ This is straightforward.

Comment: that's very nice. thanks